# Listagg + Count in Select duplicates

Tags: sql, oracle, count, listagg

I'm writing up a query and cannot seem to get over this hurdle.

I am using both LISTAGG and COUNT (side-by-side) in it and whenever I do so, the ListAgg will duplicate when count is more than 1. Moreover, it adds more into the count when the ListAgg is more than one. They're each messing with each other, and I want to know how to keep them within the same query, but keep duplicates from appearing in the ListAgg while finding only the correct amount of instances for the Count.

I've tried using DISTINCT and various groupings, but to no avail.

Here is my (simplified) SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT /*+PARALLEL */ ID, NAME, LISTAGG(USERID, ';'), COUNT(MAIN_DATA)

FROM MAIN m
JOIN USERS u on m.pk1 = u.main_pk1

WHERE MAIN_DATA like '%keyword%'
GROUP BY ID, NAME
```

which yields something similar to this:

```
ID|NAME|USERID|MAIN_DATA

1|Hello|Jim|1
2|Hi|Arthur;Arthur;Arthur|3
3|Bonjour|Jane;Jane;Jim;Jim|4
```

When ID 2 should only have Arthur once, and there are only 2 instances of the keyword in ID 3, not 4. How can I achieve this?

Comment: please show the data in the main table and the users table.

Comment: Please include the data that produces that output, and what you want to see for that data. It looks like you just have a one-to-many or many-to-many join?

Comment: Sorry to be vague, but there is multiple data instances within each ID, and only a few of them might contain 'keyword', I want to record how many instances of the Data that has that keyword. Does that help to clarify?

Comment: Multiple main items under the same PK1 value - in which case are you counting users or how many main records match that PK (!)? Or just multiple users (and the same user multiple times) under the related MAIN_PK1? Including representative data is often easier than trying to explain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, `LISTAGG()` doesn't support `DISTINCT`.

To remove duplicates, you need a subquery:

```
SELECT ID, NAME, LISTAGG(USERID, ';'), SUM(cnt)
FROM (SELECT ID, NAME, USERID, COUNT(*) as cnt
      FROM MAIN m JOIN
           USERS u 
           ON m.pk1 = u.main_pk1
      WHERE m.MAIN_DATA like '%keyword%'
      GROUP BY ID, NAME, USERID
     ) mu
GROUP BY ID, NAME;
```

Comment: Awesome! I think this will work! only other thing I have to do is divide the sum by the amount of User_id's it lists! Thank you so much!